# HTML Table issue in IE

Tags: html, html-table

I have a nested table structure like this below

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table id="tableform" cellspacing=5 cellpadding=2 class="form">
        .........
        <tr>
        <td valign="top">
    Select Columns For Report :
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Inside the table **tableform** I have created one html form.

That form has one field label **Select Columns For Report :** which is the longest label and it is getting wrapped over multiple lines in IE, which I don't want, whereas in firefox and chrome it is working properly.

Do you have any workaround for this problem in IE? If tomorrow, another longer label comes up, then what is there to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to the `td` and add [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space):

```
<td valign="top" class="nowrap">
    Select Columns For Report :
</td>

.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. no-wrap worked for me.Actually I didn't want to set the width to a fixed pixel value . **white-space: nowrap** saved my day.

Comment: But now , I have a new problem : my table is overflowing out of the containing <div> . I have tried to overcome this by using **table-layout:fixed** but to no effect. And all of this is happening in IE :(

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page or try to recreate the problem on JS Bin? It's difficult to help without seeing the problem. Also, which version(s) of IE are you testing in?

Comment: This is the link where I have uploaded the screenshot of my problem. [link](http://www.mypicx.com/08252011/HTML_Table_issue_in_IE/). I am testing in IE8.

Comment: That helps a tiny bit, but I need to see the full HTML - there's a lot going on in there. Open the page, view the source, and copy it to [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/).

Comment: Sorry @thirtydot, I was a bit busy , and so couldn't make out time to post the jsbin link. Here you go . Hope this will be useful to you.[link](http://jsbin.com/asikut/3/edit#javascript,html)

Comment: Try running the html source one in IE and one in chrome/firefox, hope you will notice the difference between the table's layout .

Comment: I have finally fixed the problem . Actually for one of the **td** elements , I had given **<td colspan="100%">** , and that's what was creating the mess I changed it to **<td colspan="2">** and now everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you need to specifically set a width for that `td`, so something like

```
    <td valign="top" style="width:200px;">
Select Columns For Report :
    </td>
```

Better yet, give it a `class` or `id` and set the width in a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either enlarge the width of the label column so that labels fit:

```
<table id="tableform" cellspacing=5 cellpadding=2 class="form">
    <col style="width: 300px" />
    ...
```

Or to set the css property `white-space` to `nowrap` on the labels:

```
<td class="label">Select Columns For Report :</td>

#tableform td.label {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```